# Undefined behavior with std::move

Tags: c++, c++11

From the [move page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) of the cppreference

> Unless otherwise specified, all standard library objects that have
>   been moved from are placed in a valid but unspecified state. That is,
>   only the functions without preconditions, such as the assignment
>   operator, can be safely used on the object after it was moved from

So, from the example on the same page, this code below is considered undefined behaviour

```
vector<string> v_string;
string example = "example";
v_string.push_back(move(example));
cout << example << endl;
```

MSVC will output nothing on the console, but if I do this

```
vector<int> v_int;
int number = 10;
v_int.push_back(move(number));
cout << number << endl;
```

will output 10. Is there a reason why this happens? Or is it always undefined behavior?

Comment: I take "valid state" to mean the objects invariants are maintained. So it should be fine to stream it to stdout, for example, but you couldn't access `example[0]` safely. I think neither of your examples shows UB.

Comment: unspecified != undefined, you can print the string but there are no guarantees as to what's inside.

Comment: Well, on all implementations that I saw, STL containers and strings simply become empty after move.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The documentation of `operator <<` for `basic_string` (C++14 21.4.8.9/5&6) does not list any preconditions, as far as I can tell.

Comment: After a string is moved there is no telling what it contains.However it will be in a well defined (if unknown to you) state internally. So sending it to `std::cout` will not destabilize the program. But it could contain everything it contained before the move or it could be empty. Typically you don't *move* an l-value unless you have no further use for it. If you do then your next action should really be to re-initialize it.

Comment: For a scalar moving is the same as copying, so the `int` stays unchanged. For your `string` example, it depends whether its `operator<<` has any preconditions, which, IIRC, it doesn't.

Comment: @Angew `operator<<` is specified in terms of `begin()`, `end()`, and `size()`, but these do not have any preconditions either. It feels right to assume that after moving, `begin()`, `end()` and `size()` are undefined, but I do not see a line of reasoning from my quick reading of the standard.

Comment: I thought that maybe the `std::move` function could be used to improve the performance not copying an object, but in fact, moving it. But this doesn't seem very reliable.

Comment: @Agostino What behavior do you expect in your example? You *move* an object into the vector, and then try to access it at the old position. What you expect to happen if you move to a new house, and I go to your old house and want to talk to you?

Comment: I know that. I didn't expect the program to print 10. What did you mean with your comment, @Jens?

Comment: @Agostino I don't understand "But this doesn't seem very reliable". What are you referring to? So I asked what behavior you expect.

Comment: @juanchopanza: *"couldn't access `example[0]` safely"* - since C++11, all valid states for a `std::string` - including "empty" - let you access `[0]` safely.  The precondition is `pos <= size()`, and `[0]` will be '\0` for an empty string.  `back()` is an example of something unsafe to call on a moved-from string without prior check for length/empty.

Comment: @TonyD Good point. UB before C++11, OK now. I should have said `example[1]` to be clear.

Comment: I suspect that if the string is short enough the Small String Optimization kicks in. In that case, you can't transfer the ownership of the buffer, as the buffer is contained within the string itself instead of being heap-allocated. As a result, it's necessary to copy such short strings (but that's OK - copying it doesn't require a heap allocation either)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unspecified does not mean undefined.

According to the C++11 standard, section 17.3.26:

> **valid but unspecified state**
>   an object state that is not specified except that the object’s invariants are met and operations on the object behave as specified for its type

As the object is in a valid state, you can stream it to an output, as streaming has no additional preconditions. However *what* is printed is unspecified, so it may just print nothing, or print that your father smells of elderberries. What you can not safely do is use a function with additional preconditions such as `back()` which additionally requires the string to be non-empty. Valid strings can be empty.

Containing the old value is a perfectly acceptable option for the unspecified but valid state. In case of fundamental types such as `int` a simple copy is just the most efficient way to perform a move.

It should also be noted that `int` is *not* a standard library object, but a fundamental type (as defined in section 3.9.1). Therefore your quote does not apply.

Comment: For reference, here is the definition from the standard: "an object state that is not specified except that the object’s invariants are met and operations on the object behave as specified for its type"

Comment: @Jens thanks, added the corresponding standard quote

Answer (score 3):

That is because a `string` can be efficiently `move`d from by stealing the pointer that points to the actual characters, so thats what compilers do, leaving the `move`d from `string` "empty". An `int` cannot be efficiently `move`d, you just make a copy. Therefore the old `int` is still there. But that is off the record. Just do not use objects that you `move`ed from and don't rely on unspecified behavior.

Comment: I don't think there's any permission for compilers to assign random values to moved ints. `std::move` merely converts its argument to an xvalue. This doesn't change the argument at all.

Answer (score 0):

Undefined behavior just means

> behavior for which this International Standard imposes no requirements.
>   Permissible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation
>   completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation
>   or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the
>   environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to
>   terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a
>   diagnostic message). Many erroneous program constructs do not engender
>   undefined behavior; they are required to be diagnosed.

If you are interested, take a look at ["What every C programmer should know about undefined behavior"](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html). It is really an eye-opener.

In your case, it is not undefined behavior but unspecified state:
In 21.4.2.16, the C++ standard defines the move constructor's semantics:

> Constructs an object of class basic_string as indicated in Table 69. 
>   The stored allocator is constructed from alloc. In the second form, str  is left in a valid state with an unspecified value.

The "second form" is the move constructor, so the string is in an unspecified state.

That means that the object must be in a state that invariants are met, but anything else is unspecified. For a string, any content would be ok.

Comment: Pretty sure there is no undefined behavior going on here, but the link is still worth reading.

Comment: @nwp I actually found a reference in the standard defining the semantics. The string is in an unspecified state. I would count this as some case of undefined behavior, although it is not the general UB.

Comment: @Jens: no, it is not a case of undefined behavior, not even some case. It might sound nitpicky, but the distinction is important: there is **no** benign undefined behavior, and any program that contains undefined behavior is broken. Unspecified state on the contrary is totally fine, as long as you do not rely on any specific state.