# Why is std::move generating instructions here?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, move

I heard time and again that `std::move(t)` is more or less only a fancy way of saying `static_cast<T&&>(t)` and would not generate any instructions.
When I was playing around now with `std::move` on godbolt in order to better understand move semantics I saw that it *does* (or at least may) generate instructions. In this example

```c++
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct S {
    S() { cout << "default ctor" << endl; }
    S(S&& s) {
        i = s.i;
        s.i = 0;
        cout << "move ctor" << endl;
    }
    int i;
};

void foo(S s) { cout << "Foo called with " << s.i << endl; }

int main() {
    S s;
    foo(static_cast<S&&>(s));
    foo(std::move(s));
}
```

the calls to `foo` lead to the following assembly output

```x86asm
        ; ... snip ...
        lea     rdi, [rbp - 16]
        lea     rsi, [rbp - 8]
        call    S::S(S&&) [base object constructor]
        lea     rdi, [rbp - 16]
        call    foo(S)
        lea     rdi, [rbp - 8]
        call    std::remove_reference<S&>::type&& std::move<S&>(S&)
        lea     rdi, [rbp - 24]
        mov     rsi, rax
        call    S::S(S&&) [base object constructor]
        lea     rdi, [rbp - 24]
        call    foo(S)
        ; ... snip ...
std::remove_reference<S&>::type&& std::move<S&>(S&): # @std::remove_reference<S&>::type&& std::move<S&>(S&)
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     qword ptr [rbp - 8], rdi
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rbp - 8]
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Can someone please explain this to me? I can't much sense of what this `std::remove_reference<S&>::type&& std::move<S&>(S&)` function is supposed to do and why there is this apparent contraction to what's commonly told.

Comment: `foo` still wants to construct its argument, it isn't a reference type. It'll use the move constructor but it will still call a constructor. `std::move` just lets the function call decide which `S` constructor to use and itself doesn't result in any assembly directly.

Comment: Where are the unexpected instructions that you think are generated by `std::move`? Can you mark them with comments in the code?

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations?

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Presumably the `call    std::remove_reference<S&>::type&& std::move<S&>(S&)` (which only appears for the second call to `foo`, prior to invoking the base object constructor). That said, presumably it's undefined behavior to try to move construct from `s` the second time (since it's already been moved-from). I'm guessing the undefined behavior here works (since `s` is empty, and the small string optimization means no dynamic memory is involved in any event), but I'd also guess you'd only see this call in a debug build; turn on even `-O1` and it should disappear.

Comment: Probably because inlining is disabled in your compiler settings

Comment: @ShadowRanger It isn't UB to access a moved-from object. It's up to each type to define its own guaranties regarding a moved-from instance. For example in this case the type `S` can guarantee that the moved from instance just have the `i` value of 0 (assuming a coherent implementation of the rule of 3/5/0).

Comment: It's UB to copy the uninitialized `i` in the move constructor though. :)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Ah, yes, ["valid but unspecified" but not "undefined" for standard library objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32346143/364696), and you can do whatever you like with your own types (though if they recursively move standard library types, they'll be unspecified).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Standard library types have different guaranties. For example `unique_ptr` always guaranties it contains `nullptr` after being moved from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are compiling without optimisations. So you see exactly what is written without any attempt to simplify or inline functions.

Generated code is roughly eqivalent to what `type&& foo(type& x) { return x; }` would generate, which is what `move` does.

Studying assembly generated without optimisations turned on is exercise in futility.

Comment: "Studying assembly generated without optimisations turned on is exercise in futility." Mind you, studying assembly with full optimizations on is an exercise in confusion and pain, so perhaps the solution is "Don't study the assembly unless profiling of the optimized code shows you've actually got a meaningful problem in that part of the code." (That said, I've found `-Os` assembly to be at least moderately understandable, so it's what I prefer for "see most optimizations, but don't unroll loops and do crazy-cross-iteration optimizations I'll never suss out"; `-O1` is probably okay too)

Comment: Yes, I was compiling without optimizations, because I wanted to know what the compiler generates in different cases (this was just stripped down to the case I was wondering about, the rest was clear) and for simple examples the optimizer can often infer too much and can optimize lots of stuff away that it can't in more complicated cases - giving you wrong intuition those cases. Maybe its best to look at it after just moderate optimizations, like ShadowRanger said.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, thinking about it again I think my question was pretty stupid in the first place. Of course, there needs to be some code generated even for an identity function if there are no optimizations. But sometimes you don't see the wood for the trees...

Comment: @ElmarZander without optimisations compiler generates code verbatim, complete with unnessesary boilerplate. That is how you get 9-instructions no-op, which could be replaces with a single `lea     rsi, [rbp - 8]`

Answer (score 6):

As for `std::remove_reference<S&>::type&& std::move<S&>(S&)`
Josuttis explains this in his C++ move semantics.

Basically what it does is similar to `static_cast<T&&>` but with the means of type traits. It allows any value category to be passed in (thus, either lvalue or rvalue reference) then it cuts off the reference part and applies to rvalue-ref one. As for the extra instructions: any optimizer should inline those calls anyway.

With optimization turned off and `foo` defined as `void foo(const S& s);` to reduce noise:

`foo(static_cast<S&&>(s));`

```
        leaq    -4(%rbp), %rax
        movq    %rax, %rdi
        call    foo(S const&)
```

`foo(std::move(s));`

```
        leaq    -4(%rbp), %rax
        movq    %rax, %rdi
        call    std::remove_reference<S&>::type&& std::move<S&>(S&)
        movq    %rax, %rdi
```

With `-O1`, both result in the same:

```
        leaq    12(%rsp), %rdi
        call    foo(S const&)
```

Comment: TL;DR unoptimized C++ is *only* for debugging when you intend to mess with program state while you are running it.

Comment: Wow, 260 pages only about c++ move semantics. Sorry, I didn't have time to read that before posting, but it's cool to have people here who did ;)

Comment: And thanks for you answer. Maybe I took that "is more or less only a static cast..." too literally. I heard Meyers say that and read it in a couple of articles, but maybe it should rather read "after a tiny bit of optimization std::move is more or less only a static cast...". I thought, if it's only a static_cast it shouldn't generate anything even without optimizations...